# What is this style of game art called?

Tags: color, android, style-identification, perspective, games

I am working on an android game, and I found this image while search for 8 bit graphics. I really like this style of the visuals, specifically the 45 degree perspective mixed with the blockiness of 8 bit graphics. Does anyone know the name of this style, and can someone point me in the right direction of a software application that could help me accomplish something similar to this?

[image]

Comment: No sprites? If they were in the screenshot, I'd be able to call it "isometric". The blockiness and restricted apllete suggests "8-bit".

Comment: I think the isometric is correct but I am not certain you can define this as 8 bit. (Ex: when you search isometric 8 bit there isn't really anything with this style)

Comment: Actually I was more confident on the "8-bit" part of that comment :) Look: low resolution, limited palette.

Comment: Its actually very high resolution. If you zoom in you can notice the very detailed shading on the edges of each block.

Comment: Not all styles have a "name" specifically. I'd just call it "8-bit" as others have mentioned, or off-axis 8-bit.

Comment: Isometric, 8-bit Voxels?

Comment: I think that is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more searching, I found a program that can accomplish this effect very easily.

As stated in one of the comments, a search in Google that leads to similar images is: 8-bit isometric voxels

http://hexraystudios.com/hexels/

Answer (score 3):

As in the comments its not really an exact style. 8bit ish, Voxel ish, basically its hipster :)

To go about making these, espescially for a game of any scale. I would use a pipeline of Illustrator (or Inkscape) and then import into Blender or another 3D program.

While you could get away with making these in a 2D program. It'll be hard to maintain consistency across scenes.

First make all your shapes in Illustrator, then import and extrude and layout in Blender. The rendering will be up to you, a simple shader with no shadows should do it.

- [Import vector to Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mihkAGfnrWA).
- [Isometric render in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QQCTPMYYs0)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a similar look in Illustrator. 
After creating objects (with pen tool or shapes), go to Effects > Stylize > Drop Shadow. 
[image: Drop shadow settings]
Just make sure there is no blur and play with the settings. 
There are tutorials about 8bit design online. If you want to copy your example, you would just need to rotate the objects (15 degrees).

Comment: Hi Fannie, although your answer is technically correct, it's not really an answer to the question is it?